# Подход к редактированию задаваемых вопросов

Tags: обсуждение

Хотел бы заручиться поддержкой опытных участников в моем подходе к редактированию поступающих вопросов (я начал было вносить изменения, но потом остановился в нерешительности).

Я не говорю о совершенно необходимой правке вопиющих нарушений норм русского языка и т. п. Речь о другом. На сайте накопилось огромное количество однотипных вопросов, например о слитном или раздельном написании слов, о значении слова, о пунктуации в конкретном предложении.  Я думаю, что если мы выработаем некие стандарты, шаблоны (пусть не очень строгие) и будем "подгонять" под них заголовки вопросов, то заинтересованному читателю легче будет ориентироваться в океане накопившихся вопросов. Пример такого шаблона: *Пунктуация в предложении: "Мое предложение"*.

Этическая сторона дела: придется без воли авторов изменять написанное ими, техническая сторона: кто-то может не найти знакомый вопрос при повторном визите на сайт. Тем не менее, я думаю, что плюсы такого подхода весомее, чем минусы. Если я получу поддержку в принципе, то перейду к деталям.

Вашу поддержку/неприятие прошу выражать в виде "плюсов" или "минусов" и в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, не вижу необходимости в шаблонах. Есть ведь метки, облегчающие поиск интересующих тем.  Лишь бы вопрос был понятен, верно сформулирован, а то иногда не поймёшь, чего от тебя хотят.

И попросить бы авторов вопросов не урезать  контекст, например, предложение писать целиком, а не только ту часть, где содержится трудность. Иногда пунктуация зависит от грамматики всего предложения, от смысла тех слов, которые как раз пропущены.

Но если  необходимость шаблонов  обусловлена облегчением в обработке и поиске  вопросов - я **ЗА**.

А вот требования к грамотности и вопросов, и ответов, мне кажется, следует ужесточить. Если это неграмотный ученик - простительно, а если человек, считающий себя почти асом в языке, который жёстко правит чужие ответы, подставляя и убирая пробелы при тире и дефисе, перед скобкой и после неё, но тут же допускает грубые орфографические ошибки, - это небрежность, граничащая с неуважением к языку, сайту, и т.д. Как -  я не знаю, может, ввести кнопку "у Вас ошибка" - пусть правит сам. У нас стало много ошибок и в ответах, и в комментариях - несерьёзно. За державу обидно.

Comment: Возвращаяь к шаблонам. Не необходимо, но, на мой взгляд, желательно. Система меток не так уж эффективна. Например по метке "слитно-раздельно" вы получаете 144 вопроса на 50 страницах. Что делать? Допустим, вы решили бегло просмотреть заголовки. Насколько проще будет, если все заголовки будут построены по одному шаблону, например **"Абвгд" — слитно или раздельно?*

Comment: Людмила! Отдельно хочу сказать спасибо за то, что ответили. Пока статистика невеселая: один ответ на 16 просмотров. А ведь это Мета, сюда заходят те, кому не все равно.

Comment: Некоторые сюда вообще не заходят. Вот если бы высвечивались новые вопросы на Мете где-нибудь сбоку от вопросов по русскому языку, люди бы видели, что они есть, и отвечали. Много ведь таких, как я, зашедших, чтобы посмотреть интересные вопросы, а не сидеть здесь часами.

Comment: Людмила, @М_Г, спасибо вам за активность на Мете! По некоторым вопросам: а) ошибки в орфографии, пунктуации и проч. в любых сообщениях — правим (но только не слишком массово, не за один раз); можно после этого оставить комментарий с вежливым замечанием; отдельной кнопки не нужно ); б) если бы мы активнее ставили голоса за вопросы на Мете, они бы высвечивались в правой части сайта; в некоторых случаях можно поставить специальную метку, и вопросы также там отобразятся (для этого через тревогу сообщите о своем замысле модераторам).

Comment: Так ведь править модераторам - слишком большая работа, это просто нечестно по отношению к ним - много времени и сил отнимает. Я знаю, что, когда тороплюсь, тоже допускаю, по своей слепоте, но стараюсь перечитывать. Надо бы как-то стимулировать, чтобы люди следили за собственной грамотностью. Это же не по незнанию.